# Розовый UI в Unity

Tags: unity3d, ui

Делал игру, делал и в одном из билдов появился заместо спрайта просто розовый квадрат, смотрел видео, менял Vulcan и DX11 местами ничего не помогло, что можно сделать с этим?

Версия Unity: 2021.3.16f1

Comment: Когда шейдер не может отрисоваться в связи с ошибкой, то он розовый. Ошибка в коде шейдера, графический API не поддерживает шейдер, рендер пайплайн не работает с шейдером.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Это из-за того что картинка была скорее всего утеряна (удалена). Проверьте как вариант.